# Store Path as String Applescript

Tags: path, applescript, filepath, finder, applescript-objc

In my Applescript, I'm choosing a file of which I would like to store the path (to be opened later).

When I tried storing the path of the file as a string, this is the error I received:

> error "Can’t make path of alias \"Macintosh
>   HD:Users:Username:Desktop:Folder:File.xls\" into type string." number -1700
>   from path of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Username:Desktop:Folder:File.xls" to string

How can I effectively store this file path, so that I may recall it later when opening this file?

**Applescript:**

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePath to path of (choose file) as string
    set fileName to name of file filePath
end tell
```

*Note: I also tried `as text`.

Comment: This would work if you move the first line outside the Finder tell block of code and also remove the words "path of".

Comment: Maybe I'm totally misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but isn't this easier than the accepted answer? `set thisPOSIXPath to (the POSIX path of oldPath)` (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Aliases_and_paths)

Comment: In case you want to convert a path to a string in Apple Javascript (instead of AppleScript)  you can do `String(filePath)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePathAlias to (choose file)
    set fileName to name of filePathAlias
    set filePath to filePathAlias as string
end tell
```

Comment: I would add to this that you shouldn't have commands inside an application tell block of code if it's not needed. It's inefficient and could potentially cause problems. As such only your second line needs the Finder (getting the file name), so you should move the first and third lines outside the Finder tell block.